# How to check if user is logged in to a workstation, or workstation is locked?

Tags: c, windows

Is there a function or a simple way to check if a user is logged in to a workstation or the workstation is locked? And if it is possible, then how to check who is logged on if the workstation is locked?

Thanks!

Comment: Remotely? From a service? Do we need to account for {Fast User Switching/Terminal Services}?

Comment: @Damien: Not remotely, my application will run on the local machine. If it is possible, than i don't want to create a service. It would be easier for me to create a simple Console Application. If there is no other way, than of course i will make a service.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running as a service, you'd register a [HandlerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) callback function, and track SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE events.

If you're pumping windows messages, then you'd want to track WM_SESSION_CHANGE and WTS_SESSION_LOGON messages. To get the latter, you'd have to call [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

To query a remote machine, you'd probably use [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).